# Make a public var equal to private string

Tags: ios, string, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I want a public variable to be equal to the string I get inside a method that is generated by a call I made

Here is the `func` I use to make a call to get the tempString

```
func handleSnapshotResult(snapshot: Dictionary<String, String>) -> Void
{
    let tempString : String = snapshot["temperature"]!
    println("TEMPERATURE: " + tempString)
}
```

I want to use the tempString inside of a uicollectionview cell, how do I make a public variable to set the `CollectionViewCell.label.text = temp string`

BTW im new to swift

Answer (score 1):

You can put this call where you create and set text of the cell. When you get response from your call you just set the text

```
CollectionViewCell.label.text = "YOUR_RESPONSE_TEXT"
```

You can skip the function for this call.

Comment: is this a web call for "snapshot["temperature"]!" value?

Comment: I never user  parse.com, tell me can u make this call in cellForItemAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Yes but that will not help you

Comment: then call it in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method after calling set the value to label.

Comment: nope, you will then only create an instance of that function inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, and you still cannot set label.text = temperature

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a public variable just where your class definition starts. So something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    var temperature = ""

    [...]
}
```

After this, when your method returns the value that you want to set, you have to update your collection view by calling its `reloadData` method.

```
func handleSnapshotResult(snapshot: Dictionary<String, String>) -> Void {
    temperature = snapshot["temperature"]!
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath(_:)` method you can update your label like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = temperature

    return cell
}
```

Comment: var temperature will still be equal to nil

Comment: Will it could be nil if `snapshot["temperature"]` is nil.

Comment: no , var temperature will only be equal to snapshot["temperature"]  inside the func handleSnapshotResult(snapshot: Dictionary<String, String>) -> Void